# Error con StreamController: Bad State:Stream has already been listened to

Tags: flutter, dart

Buen día, me encuentro trabajando en un proyecto donde requiero usar notificaciones y dirigir al usuario a una pantalla desde la notificación.

Todo funciona correctamente excepto por este error: **Bad State:Stream has already been listened to.**

Se que el error se debe a que cuando la aplicación cae de nuevo a la pantalla de inicio el stream ya esta en modo listen y salta el error.

Este es mi código:

Estoy usando un StreamController para escuchar la informacion de la notificacion:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:ruitoquefood/modelos/notificacion.dart';

StreamController<Notificacion> streamController = new StreamController();
```

En mi archivo main.dart recibo la notificacion y la agrego al stream:

```
OneSignal.shared
        .setNotificationOpenedHandler((OSNotificationOpenedResult result) {
      var data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;
      Notificacion notificacion = Notificacion.fromJson(data);
      streamController.add(notificacion);
    });
```

En mi pagina de inicio en el iniState leo la informacion del StreamController:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    streamController.stream.listen((event) {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, event.pagina, arguments: event.id);
    });
    cargarComercios(context);
    deepNavigator(context);
  }
```

Ahora, investigando un poco se que se puede solucionar agregando un broadcast al stream, pero lastimosamente si hago esto, cuando la aplicación esta cerrada no funciona la navegación desde la notificación.

Creo que lo mas conveniente es hacer close del stream en el dispose de la pagina de inicio, pero no encuentro la forma de realizar un pushReplacement eliminando todas las rutas antes de que la aplicacion vuelva a la pagina de inicio.

Lo estoy haciendo de este modo pero no hace el dispose de la pagina de inicio y obviamente salta el error:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('inicio',(Route<dynamic> route) =>false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Por defecto, los streams están hecho para solo tener un listener, debes de cerrar el listener anterior o bien transformar tu Stream para que múltiples objetos puedan escuchar sus emisiones, para eso cambia esto:

```
StreamController<Notificacion> streamController = new StreamController();
```

Por esto:

```
StreamController<Notificacion> streamController = new StreamController.broadcast();
```

Comment: Fernando que grata sorpresa. Uno mas de tus alumnos aquí. Veras, eso funciona y me deja de dar errores, el problema es que cuando la aplicación esta cerrada y llega la notificación, al abrirla no hace la navegación hasta la pantalla final. Es decir, si agrego el broadcast la app solo abre hasta el inicio y no ejecuta el Navigator.pushNamed. Pero si quito el broadcast si funciona